# SQL Query Between Dates AND Based on Employee Name

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql, azure

I have a SQL Azure database with two main tables that I am trying to join via a view.  I have it working, but the execution time is in excess of 2 minutes.

Here are the main tables and columns I'm dealing with:

TransactionsTable:

```
PostedDate          | EmployeeFirstName | EmployeeLastName | DollarsCollected | UserName
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
09/08/2017 09:05 am | 'John'            | 'Smith'          |            42.25 | 'john.smith'
09/08/2017 09:07 am | 'Jane'            | 'Jones'          |            58.50 | 'jane.jones'
09/08/2017 09:15 am | 'Tom'             | 'Holland'        |            62.75 | 'tom.holland' 
09/08/2017 09:17 am | 'John'            | 'Smith'          |            48.50 | 'john.smith'    
09/08/2017 09:19 am | 'Jane'            | 'Jones'          |            32.25 | 'jane.jones'
```

CustomerHistory

```
CustomerID | StartDate           | Duration | UserName      | TransactionType
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
         1 | 09/08/2017 09:02 am |      600 | 'john.smit'h  | 'PropertyTax'
         2 | 09/08/2017 09:03 am |      500 | 'tom.holland' | 'TagRenewal'
         3 | 09/08/2017 09:04 am |      450 | 'jane.jones'  | 'PropertyTax'
         4 | 09/08/2017 09:12 am |      700 | 'john.smith'  | 'TagRenewal'
         5 | 09/08/2017 09:16 am |      300 | 'jane.jones'  | 'TagRenewal'
```

So, the deal here is - one employee can only have one customer at one time.  If we know what time a transaction was posted and we know what employee posted it, then we should be able to connect that information to the CustomerHistory table by using the `StartDate` and `StartDate + Duration` as sort of an "umbrella" of the total transaction.  Consider `StartDate + Duration` to be equal to `EndDate`.  So, here's the query I'm trying to run to accomplish this:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    CustomerHistory
    JOIN TransactionsTable ON
        CustomerHistory.UserName = TransactionsTable.UserName
        AND
        TransactionsTable.PostedDate >= CustomerHistory.StartDate
        AND
        TransactionsTable.PostedDate <= DATEADD( ss, CustomerHistory.StartDate, CustomerHistory.Duration )
```

For reference, I have indexes on the `UserName` fields as well as the date fields.  Suffice it to say I'm oversimplifying my tables here, as there are many more columns of data from each table I am hoping to join.  I have run the execution plan in SQL Server, and it tells me that the Hash Match will take about 38% of my execution time, and the table scan on the transaction table will take 42%.  I am decent with SQL but have never delved into a query quite as resource intensive as what I'm dealing with here, and its putting quite a load on my server trying to run it this way.

Can anyone help?

Comment: This is where i oversimplified my sample a bit.  I am able to do a join on a third table called Users where I have a First Name, Last Name, and user name field.  Even when doing that, I'm still running at 2-3 minutes on this query.

For purposes of this, just assume that both tables have a UserName field.  I will edit my initial question to reflect this.

Comment: `I have indexes on the UserName fields as well as the date fields` You might want to consider `INCLUDE`ing the `Duration` column in your date index, that way SQL Server can use that index to get its hands on `StartDate` and `Duration` from the same index

Comment: Which are Tables and which are Views? Your question doesn't say.

Comment: Both of these shown are tables.  I'm trying to create a view from them, which is when I run into the bottleneck. Though, trying to run the query that I intend to build the view from is just as slow (which makes sense).

I will give the duration index a go tomorrow and see where that lands me.  Thank you for helping!

Comment: I think you have your arguments mixed up in the dateadd function. How many rows are in each table?

Comment: Side note, why not a procedure? It sounds like you actually want to parameterize it. Are you going to be querying real time data? If not you could always materialize the view.

Comment: Using a function in a join will cause a table scan.  Better approach would be to store the finish time instead of duration :: or use a persisted computed column for the finish time.

Comment: Persisted computed column and associated indexes have been created, that was a great suggestion.  Yes, i will be querying fairly real-time data.  At least up to the hour or so.  I suppose I could run a stored procedure hourly to create a computed table with all of the data in it.  That computation would happen faster than the data is updating anyway.  Still, kind of clunky.

Answer (score 0):

It's tricky to speed up because your query is non-SARGable. Adding a persisted computed column I believe should work quite well for your query. You will want to read up on it though because this ***can slow*** DML(inserts,updates, and deletes).

My creation scripts of your table for reference(SQL Fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f1a39/8):

```
Create Table dbo.TransactionsTable
(
  PostedDate Datetime,
  EmployeeFirstName Varchar(100),
  EmployeeLastName Varchar(100),
  DollarsCollected Money,
  UserName Varchar(100)
);

Create Table dbo.CustomerHistory
(
  CustomerID Int,
  StartDate DateTime,
  Duration Int,
  UserName Varchar(100),
  TransactionType Varchar(100)
);


Insert Into dbo.TransactionsTable
Values 
('09/08/2017 09:05 am','John','Smith',42.25 , 'john.smith'),
('09/08/2017 09:07 am','Jane','Jones',58.50 , 'jane.jones'),
('09/08/2017 09:15 am','Tom','Holland',62.75 , 'tom.holland'), 
('09/08/2017 09:17 am','John','Smith',48.50 , 'john.smith'),    
('09/08/2017 09:19 am','Jane','Jones',32.25 , 'jane.jones');
GO

Insert Into dbo.CustomerHistory
  Values (1,'09/08/2017 09:02 am',600,'john.smith' ,'PropertyTax'),
         (2,'09/08/2017 09:03 am',500,'tom.holland','TagRenewal'),
         (3,'09/08/2017 09:04 am',450,'jane.jones','PropertyTax'),
         (4,'09/08/2017 09:12 am',700,'john.smith','TagRenewal'),
         (5,'09/08/2017 09:16 am',300,'jane.jones','TagRenewal');
Go
```

Make sure you have this index.

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX ix_test1
  ON TransactionsTable(UserName,PostedDate) 
  Include (EmployeeFirstName,EmployeeLastName,DollarsCollected);
GO
```

For customer history, can you add a persisted column? Then index the column

```
Alter Table CustomerHistory
Add EndDate As (DateAdd(ss,Duration,StartDate)) Persisted;
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX ix_test2
  ON CustomerHistory(UserName,StartDate,EndDate)
  Include(CustomerID,TransactionType);
GO
```

Here's the query

```
SELECT *
FROM CustomerHistory AS A
INNER JOIN TransactionsTable AS B
  ON A.UserName = B.UserName
  AND B.PostedDate Between A.StartDate And A.EndDate;
```

Comment: Really good suggestions here, and I've implemented them all.  Unfortunately no improvement in the speed of the query.  I'm thinking the query could be sped up by only looking for the first entry that matches.  In other words, the query is looking for all transactions that were posted between start date and end date, but really there should only ever be one.  So, it can stop looking after the first.  I imagine I would need to use row() and partition_by to make this happen but that is not my strong suit.  Any thoughts?

Comment: What query are you using? Also can you screenshot the execution plan and run the query with "set statistics io on" and added the messages results to the question.